# Is the fortune wheel deterministic?

Tags: happy-street

I have noticed that when I "click" the fortune wheel it seems to always drift a few spaces and then land.  Is this a deterministic behavior?  In other words, can I time my spin to land on a particular space - or are the results determined by the server and it doesn't really make a difference when I "click"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive testing, I have determined that **yes, it is deterministic**.  In order to predict the outcome, you need only tap the spinning wheel when your target is directly at the bottom of the wheel.  As the wheel slows, whatever was directly at the bottom will be where it stops.

I have also noted that the wheel spins at different rates.  I'm not sure if it start slow each day and progresses faster with each subsequent spin, or if the speed is random.  When it is going very slow, the deterministic nature is easy to verify.